# How to change url webform entry textfiled to link in views?

Tags: webforms

I have url data (for example http://testtt.infoo) submitted from webform (component textfield).

When I display by using Views, this looks like text. I hope I can click it and open the url site.

What should I do to make that url data displayed as clickable link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the component value which stores the URL to your View. Configure the field and choose to 'exclude from display'. Add a new custom Global: custom text field to your view. Choose Rewrite results -> output this field as link. In the link path field choose the URL component value from the replacements values list.